# How would I fix this script with the wrong output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, subprocess, sys

It is messing up in multiple ways

Here is the code:

```py
import threading
import sys
import time
import os
import subprocess
import requests
import threading

ip = sys.argv[1:]

website_loaded = False

def verify():
    while website_loaded == False:
        sys.stdout.write("Verifying IP    \r")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sys.stdout.write("Verifying IP.   \r")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sys.stdout.write("Verifying IP..  \r")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sys.stdout.write("Verifying IP... \r")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        continue

verify_thread = threading.Thread(target = verify, args = ())
verify_thread.start()

ping = os.system("ping %s >nul" % str(ip))
ipVerification = subprocess.getoutput(str(ping))

website_loaded = True
if ipVerification == "Ping request could not find host %s. Please check the name and try again." % ip:
    print("Invalid IP. Please try again")
    print("Press any key to exit")
    os.system("pause >nul")
    exit()
elif ipVerification.find('PING: transmit failed. General failure.') != -1:
    print("Invalid IP. Please try again")
    print("Press any key to exit")
    os.system("pause >nul")
    exit()
website_loaded = False

def loading():
    while website_loaded == False:
        sys.stdout.write("Loading    \r")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sys.stdout.write("Loading.   \r")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sys.stdout.write("Loading..  \r")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sys.stdout.write("Loading... \r")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        continue

loading_thread = threading.Thread(target = loading, args = ())
loading_thread.start()

info = requests.get("http://ip-api.com/json/%s" % ip).json()

website_loaded = True

print(info)
```

When I type "ipinfo.py 55" in cmd, the output is "{'message': 'invalid query', 'query': '[]', 'status': 'fail'}
Loading... P..." which I have no idea why. I expect it to say that the IP is invalid, but for some reason it is doing this weird thing

Comment: The variable `ip` is a list, so you're actually making this request: http://ip-api.com/json/['55']

Comment: @rdas How would I make it not a list?

Comment: `ip = sys.argv[1]`

Comment: @rdas that gives the error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: You're not calling the script with at least one argument.

Comment: @rdas Isn't 55 the argument? If not, how would I do an argument?

Comment: It should be. But seems that it's not getting passed (and the error you posted confirms that). Can you add exactly how you are calling the script to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab a single IP do:

```
ip = sys.argv[1]
```

If you want proper command line handling look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

You don't need to do `os.system` if you are using `subprocess`. Instead of:

```
ping = os.system("ping %s >nul" % str(ip))
ipVerification = subprocess.getoutput(str(ping))
```

you could do:

```
ipVerification = subprocess.getoutput(f"ping {ip}")
```

and when `ip = 55` this value of `ipVerification` is:

```
connect: Invalid argument
```

This will allow you to catch it before calling the `ip-api.com` API. Alternatively, you can ignore the ping and let the `message` in the response from `ip-api.com` determine whether the IP address was valid.

```
if response.get("message") == "invalid query":
    print(f"The IP address is invalid: {ip}".
else:
    print(response.get("isp"))
```

Comment: When I do this, it says `IndexError: list index out of range` for ip = sys.argv[1]

Comment: Like you said you did `ipinfo.py 55` or `python ipinfo.py 55`.

Comment: Now if the IP is invalid, it says `{'message': 'invalid query', 'query': 'invalid_ip', 'status': 'fail'} Loading... P...` and if it is valid it gives the information, then says `Loading... P...`

Comment: If you are talking about the `if response.get("message") == "invalid query":
    print(f"The IP address is invalid: {ip}".
else:
    print(response.get("isp"))` then yes I did replace my if and elif with that, except it gives me the error where response is not defined